# Which example can show that the conclusion may fail if we remove the hypothesis $f(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)$ exists and finite for all $x \in (0,1)$. Suppose further $f'(x)$ is incresing on $(0,1)$. Show that $f(x)/x$ is also incresing on $(0,1)$.Give an example to show that this conclusion can fail if we remove the hypothesis that $f(0)=0$.

I have done the first part but can't think of any example which will show the conclusion can fail. I want a proper example. Thank you.

Comment: Nearly any example will work! Start with an increasing function $f'(x)$, find an antiderivative $f(x)$ such that $f(0)>0$, and check $f(x)/x$. The point is that if $f(0)>0$ then $\lim_{x\to0+} f(x)/x = \infty$, which really rules out the possibility that $f(x)/x$ is increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)/x$ is increasing on $(0, 1)$ then
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{x} \le \frac{f(1/2)}{1/2} \implies f(x) \le 2x f(\frac 12)
$$
for $0 < x < 1/2$. It follows that $f(0) \le 0$, so that is a *necessary* condition: The conclusion fails for all functions with $f(0) > 0$.

A concrete example is $f(x) = 1 + x^2$. $f'(x) = 2x$ is increasing, but $f(x)/x = x + 1/x$ is *decreasing* on $(0, 1)$.

The conclusion is true if $f(0) \le 0$: An increasing derivative means that $f$ is convex. Writing the convexity condition for $0 < x < y$ and using $f(0) \le 0$ shows that $f(x)/x \le f(y)/y$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x) = 3/4 + (x-1/2)^2$ for a counterexample.